# javascript if else statement problem

Tags: javascript

```
<?php $genderdb = "Male"?>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var genderdb = "<?php echo $genderdb; ?>";
        if ((genderdb == "Female") || ($genderdb == "Shemale")) {
            var himher = "her";
        } else {
            var himher = "him";
        }
        alert (himher);
</script>
```

If I change php `$genderdb = "Female"`, then it can alert the value successful. But if $genderdb = "Male", the page won't have alert. Why? Where is the error?

Comment: Is that `$` supposed to be there in the JavaScript if?

Comment: @CD Sanchez: That's an answer. Post it, and I'll vote it up. Good eye. @zac1987: JavaScript expressions are short-circuited. When `genderdb == "Female"`, the `if` condition is `true` and so the second half doesn't have to be evaluated at all. If `genderdb != "Female"`, the second half of that condition has to be evaluated, resulting in an undefined symbol error. You should be seeing it in the JavaScript console of whatever browser you're using.

Comment: For reference, you can use `<?=$genderdb?>` instead of `<?php echo $genderdb; ?>`

Comment: @Jamie: (a) only if you have short_tags enabled; (b) please do not.

Comment: @Jamie: Only if the shorttags option is turned on, which it isn't necessarily.

Comment: LOL. Sorry about this silly mistake. Problem is fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if ((genderdb == "Female") || ($genderdb == "Shemale")) {
```

should be

```
if ((genderdb == "Female") || (genderdb == "Shemale")) {
```

It works when `genderdb` is `"Female"`, because then the (broken) second comparison doesn't come into the equation.

In addition, using `var` inside the conditional blocks is suspect. Javascript actually doesn't have block scope so it works, but it's something to consider.

Comment: Re `var`: Yes, it's *specifically* allowed by the spec to repeat a `var` within an execution context (logic flow has no effect whatsoever on `var`, it's evaluated upon *entry* to a context), but it's not a good idea.

Comment: what is blocks? Do you mean I must not use var? If so, what should I use?

Comment: @zac1987: Since it's not a problematic issue here, and quite complex to explain in a comment, I think I'll actually leave the topic for another day.

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in this line:

```
if ((genderdb == "Female") || ($genderdb == "Shemale")) {
```

Namely, the second reference to `genderdb` uses the name of the PHP variable, instead of the JavaScript variable.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `$` from your 'shemale' comparison.

That's causing your script to fail as it's looking for a non-existent variable.

```
        var genderdb = "<?php echo $genderdb; ?>";
        if ((genderdb == "Female") || (genderdb == "Shemale")) {
            var himher = "her";
        } else {
            var himher = "him";
        }
        alert (himher);
```